# Sudo apt update: How to Avoid a Google Package from Updating Itself?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ubuntu-sdk

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, the following package is updated as well:
[image]

Is there any way to suppress this, and/or remove this package completely? I had thought that I had installed google-cloud-sdk completely, but apparently not..

When I open the program `Software & Updater` and then go to the tab `Other Software`, there is no option to remove this package.

When I run `sudo apt-get purge google-cloud-sdk`, I get the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are referring to is about a repository not a package - repositories hold packages and `sudo apt update` refreshes the local cache with the info from the repositories.

To remove a repository there are several possibilities:

**1. Using CLI**

Normally all repositories are listed under `/etc/apt/sources.list` - so you could either open that file via `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` (replace nano with vi or emacs if you like). Then delete the corresponding line or comment it out by putting a `#` at the beginning.

Sometimes the repository is saved to a seperate file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` in this case you might just want to delete the corresponding file with `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` (the file might be named differently).

**2. The GUI way**

Open the Application "Software & Updates" head to the tab "Other Software" and either uncheck the Box in front of the repository or click on the repository and hit the Button "remove".

For more info about repositories and how they work you might have a look at these ( a little bit older) wiki pages:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine